Communicating with a Kafka server from a Python app using the Twisted framework
I have an app written using the Twisted framework, that communicates various data (mostly - log entries in JSON format) to a variety of logging servers using output plug-ins. I would like to make it able to send the data to a Kafka server, too - but I am hitting some kind of problem that I don't know how to solve.
If I send data to the Kafka server in a straightforward way using Python and the kafka-python module, everything works just fine:
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

site = '<KAFKA SERVER>'
port = 9092
username = '<USERNAME>'
password = '<PASSWORD>'
topic = 'test'

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='{}:{}'.format(site, port),
    value_serializer=lambda v: bytes(str(dumps(v)).encode('utf-8')),
    sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256',
    security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
    sasl_plain_username=username,
    sasl_plain_password=password
)

event = {
    'message': 'Test message'
}

try:
    producer.send(topic, event)
    producer.flush()
    print('Message sent.')
except Exception as e:
    print('Error producing message: {}'.format(e))
finally:
    producer.close()

However, if I try to send it from my actual Twisted app, using pretty much the same code, it hangs:
from json import dumps

from core import output
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from twisted.python.log import msg

class Output(output.Output):

    def start(self):
        site = '<KAFKA SERVER>'
        port = 9092
        username = '<USERNAME>'
        password = '<PASSWORD>'
        self.topic = 'test'
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers='{}:{}'.format(site, port),
            value_serializer=lambda v: bytes(str(dumps(v)).encode('utf-8')),
            sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256',
            security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
            sasl_plain_username=username,
            sasl_plain_password=password
        )

    def stop(self):
        self.producer.flush()
        self.producer.close()

    def write(self, event):
        try:
            self.producer.send(self.topic, event)
            self.producer.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            msg('Kafka error: {}'.format(e))

(This won't run out-of-the box; it's just the plug-in and uses a generic Output class defined elsewhere.)
In particular, it hangs at the self.producer.send(self.topic, event) line.
I think that the problem comes from the fact that the Kafka producer in kafka-python is synchronous (blocking) and Twisted requires asynchronous (non-blocking) code. There is an asynchronous Kafka module, called afkak - but it doesn't seem to provide authentication with the Kafka server, so it is not suitable for my needs.
The way I understand it, the way to get around such problems in Twisted is to use deferreds. However, I have been unable to understand how exactly to do it. If I rewrite the write method like this
    def write(self, event):
        d = threads.deferToThread(self.postentry, event)
        d.addCallback(self.postentryCallback)
        return d

    def postentryCallback(self):
        reactor.stop()

    def postentry(self, event):
        try:
            self.producer.send(self.topic, event)
            self.producer.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            msg('Kafka error: {}'.format(e))

it no longer hangs when trying to send data to the Kafka server - but it hangs when the application terminates and nothing is send to the Kafka server anyway (which I can verify with a separate, consumer script, written in pure Python).
Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?
Twisted has an asynchronous implementation of some typical otherwise blocking code, like making GET/POST requests to a web server - but Kafka is not a web server, it runs on port 9092, so I don't think that I can use that.

What about aiokafka?

aiokafka is supposed to be a Python module for asynchronous communication with a Kafka server - but I couldn't make it work.
Eventually, I solved my problem with the confluent-kafka module. Unfortunately, it is not a drop-in replacement for the kafka-python module, so the code had to be rewritten a bit:
from json import dumps

from core import output
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from twisted.python.log import msg


class Output(output.Output):

    def start(self):
        site = <KAFKA SERVER>
        port = 9092
        username = '<USERNAME>'
        password = '<PASSWORD>'
        self.topic = 'test'
        self.producer = Producer({
            'bootstrap.servers': '{}:{}'.format(site, port),
            'sasl.mechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-256',
            'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
            'sasl.username': username,
            'sasl.password': password
        })

    def stop(self):
        self.producer.flush()

    def write(self, event):
        self.postentry(event)

    def delivery_callback(self, err, message):
        if err:
            msg('Kafka error: {}'.format(err))

    def postentry(self, event):
        try:
            self.producer.produce(
                self.topic,
                bytes(str(dumps(event)).encode('utf-8')),
                callback=self.delivery_callback
            )
            self.producer.poll(0)
            self.producer.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            msg('Kafka error: {}'.format(e))

